# How to secure classic ASP ASPSESSIONID cookie?

Tags: session, cookies, asp-classic

Is there a way to mark classic ASP ASPSESSIONID* cookies as secure?  It appears that the ASP ISAPI handler adds that session id cookie after my page is done rendering so putting code at the end of my page to loop through the Response.Cookie collection and mark them as secure doesn't seem to touch the ASPSESSIONID* cookie.  Any other way of doing this?

Comment: Answer adjusted, there is a way to do this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

<strike>The answer is no there isn't</strike> There isn't on the standard UI provided by IIS manager.  However, you can enable secure cookies for the SessionID via the [AspKeepSessionIDSecure](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/0d49cbc8-10e1-4fa8-ba61-c34e524a3ae6.mspx?mfr=true) Metabase value

Comment: Since my site is expecting that all communication is via https, I'd like to know that the cookie won't be transmitted insecure.  Pages 8-10 of the following document explain why the secure flag is needed:

http://www.isecpartners.com/files/web-session-management.pdf

Comment: Assuming all traffic is over HTTPS then it won't be.  There is a possiblity that it might be if the user removes the 's' from http and tries to talk to your site.  But even if they do what is the harm in that if your site only uses Https?

Comment: I completely agree with you that it is far fetched, but one of our clients, in reviewing our code, brought this up as an issue.  Not a high priority issue, but something I wanted to investigate.

Even though the server doesn't talk http, the browser doesn't know that and will send the cookie over http since the Secure bit is not set on the cookie.

Comment: BTW, this link: http://www.microsoft.com/technet/security/bulletin/MS00-080.mspx

Makes me think it is possible or even supported.  The article talks about IIS4 or 5, but I am running 5.1 and 6.

Do you have documentation that supports your answer of "No, it is not possible"?

Comment: No, in fact I've just found some documentation that shows how it is possible ;).

Comment: Reference for what @slolife's customer might have been worried about: https://resources.enablesecurity.com/resources/Surf%20Jacking.pdf. The short of it is that even with a site that is only accessible by HTTPS cookies that aren't secure can be stolen by a man-in-the-middle.

Comment: @Tyler:  Yes that is exactly the sort of attack that enabling `AspKeepSessionIDSecure` is designed to prevent.

Comment: Whoops, misread the comment context. Well, the link's good anyway ;)

Answer (score 3):

I run this command:
[CSCRIPT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490887.aspx) C:\Inetpub\AdminScripts\adsutil.vbs set w3svc/1/AspKeepSessionIDSecure 1
More information here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rahulso/archive/2007/06/19/cookies-case-study-with-ssl-and-frames-classic-asp.aspx

Comment: Handy script. Note have run this once for each desired website by ... set w3svc/[site identifier here]/AspKeepSessionIdSecure 1

Answer (score 3):

As found [here](https://forums.iis.net/post/1963706.aspx), an [UrlRewrite](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) rule can handle this.

The rules below handle it for adding both `HttpOnly` and `Secure` if they are missing on the `ASPSESSIONID` cookie. (For other cookies, normally they are emitted by the site ASP code: better handle that directly in the code responsible for them.)

```
<system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
    <outboundRules>
      <rule name="Add HttpOnly" preCondition="No HttpOnly">
        <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Set_Cookie" pattern="\s*ASPSESSIONID.*" />
        <action type="Rewrite" value="{R:0}; HttpOnly" />
      </rule>
      <rule name="Add Secure" preCondition="No Secure">
        <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Set_Cookie" pattern="\s*ASPSESSIONID.*" />
        <action type="Rewrite" value="{R:0}; Secure" />
        <conditions>
          <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="localhost" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
      </rule>
      <preConditions>
        <preCondition name="No HttpOnly">
          <add input="{RESPONSE_Set_Cookie}" pattern="; HttpOnly" negate="true" />
        </preCondition>
        <preCondition name="No Secure" logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
          <add input="{RESPONSE_Set_Cookie}" pattern="; Secure" negate="true" />
        </preCondition>
      </preConditions>
    </outboundRules>
  </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

If [UrlRewrite](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) is not installed in the IIS Server, this will crash the site.

Note that the `Secure` rule should not be applied if the site is legitimately accessed over `http` instead of `https`, thus the condition for not emitting it when browsing it locally. If `Secure` is emitted for a site accessed over `http` from the client end, the client will not send the cookie back to the server.

(I avoid testing the inbound protocol, because the sites I work on are not supposed to be accessed on `http` anyway, excepted eventually directly from their hosting server or load-balancer.)

I have previously tried using [asp/session/keepSessionIdSecure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/asp/session#attributes), but it has no effect (at least for a site behind a load-balancer terminating the https and accessing the site server over http). This setting is the modern version (IIS 7+) of the `AspKeepSessionIDSecure` Metabase value pointed by [AnthonyWJones answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/954665/1178314).

Answer (score 1):

[Edit: You can ignore the following.  I just realized that you were talking about ASPSESSIONID.}

There is built-in support for secure cookies.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524757.aspx

Example **(for ASP.Net, not Classic ASP)**:

```
Response.Cookies("setSecure") = "someValue"
Response.Cookies("setSecure").Secure = true
```

Comment: The question is about Classic ASP not asp.net